# Ошибка открытия логов Sinumerik 840D

Tags: администрирование

Всем привет!
На станке Multiturn 4500 AS Coburg, на стойке siemens Sinumerik 840D на внутренней сети станка был изменён айпишник, какой был старый никто не знает. Похоже, что по этой сети стойка связывалась с контроллером PLC. При загрузке HMI выводит ошибку: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибки появляются одна за другой и легко убираются. Далее спокойно загружается HMI.
Ни в редакторе реестра, ни в журнале винды (Windows XP) мы не нашли файл откуда вызывается данная сеть и кто запрашивает её. Пробовали ставить wireshark, он не видит вообще никаких сетей, соответственно трасировку сделать не получается. На станке стоит ещё 1 компьютер для инструментального магазина откуда мы взяли шлюз, и примерный айпишник и смогли через стойку к нему подключится. Айпишник для внутренней подсетки задали наугад и появилось даже какое-то соединение, но с чем, не понятно.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кто-то сталкивался с подобным, прошу помочь в решении проблемы.

Comment: А самими Сименсам присать пробовали?

Comment: Нет, для этого сертификат техподдержки нужен.

Comment: Так, но если у вас уже есть сетка после "ip наугад", то теперь можно же вайршарк поковырять?

Comment: Вайршарк всё-рвно ничего не видит, для него сетей не существует.

Comment: Кто-нить у вас знает где ещё может быть установлена такая связка железа? Обычно тусовка крайне маленькая и все друг друга знают чуть ли не в лицо.

Comment: Нет, никто не знает! Такой связки железа больше нет. Проблему мы так и не устранили, станок работает с ней.

Comment: Так. А если у вас при айпишнике наугад появилась какая-то сеть - значит можно теперь просканить nmap-он диапазон адресов и все порты и посмотреть кто отзовётся.